# Perl glob, qq(), and brackets []

Tags: perl, glob, string-interpolation

I have two directories with a file in each:

```sh
$ ls -l "test dir["
-rw-r--r--  1 root  media     0B 11 Dec 16:53 .ignoreme
```

and

```sh
$ ls -l "test [dir]"
-rw-r--r--  1 root  media     0B 11 Dec 16:34 .ignoreme
```

and I'm using Perl to test for the existence of the ".ignoreme" file:

```sh
$ perl -e '$d="test dir["; print -e glob qq("$d"/.ignore*); print "\n";'
1
```

which works, and

```sh
$ perl -e '$d="test [dir]"; print -e glob qq("$d"/.ignore*); print "\n";'
```

which doesn't.

I'm guessing it has to do with the `[]` pair but I'm unsure as to the interaction.  Can someone please enlighten me.  I'd be grateful for a fix too for matching any `$d` that includes `[]`.

Answer (score 7):

The `glob` interprets the pair `[]` as meta-characters for a *character class*.<sup>†</sup> This is easily confirmed with a simple experiment

```
mkdir zZ
touch zZ/f.txt
perl -wE'say for glob qq([az][bZ]/*)'
```

This correctly lists the file.

Then in the second case in the question the `glob` doesn't at all look for a directory with literal `[]` in its name, but for a directory with either one of `d,i,r` characters following `test␣` in its name.

One fix then is to use `\Q...\E` (see [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)) in order to escape those `[]`

```
say for glob qq(\Q$d\E/.ignore*);
```

This also escapes spaces, just as needed -- but then it does escape other things as well, so you can't use wildcards (for one) for what is inside the sequence.  This shouldn't ever be a problem as a directory name won't have characters meant to act as wildcards but it is good to keep it in mind.

Another option is to escape special characters when forming the directory name variable

```
 perl -wE'$d = quotemeta "test [dir]"; say for glob qq($d/*)'
```

what now works as usual.

There is no need for double quoting with this since `quotemeta` takes care of spaces as well.

---

<sup>†</sup>  The [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) page says

> This operator is implemented using the standard `File::Glob` extension.

and [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) docs specifically list `[]` as meta-characters, for *character class*.

Comment: The solution is correct, but I don't know about the explanation. `-d` would be calling `stat` whereas `glob` is using Perl's own glob implementation. `stat qq("test dir")` doesn't work because there's no shell interpretation, but `glob qq("test dir")` works fine. `glob qq("$d"/.ignore*)` should work, it's explicitly recommended [in the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to use quotes like that. I'm guessing there's a bug in Perl's glob implementation.

Comment: @Schwern  Yes, I'm now doubting the explanation as well ... working on it.  I confirmed it, the first case works and the second doesn't! (One after another in one one-liner, or in separate ones.) Go figure. Thank you for the comment

Comment: @Schwern, The docs clearly show `*` working in side of the quotes (since `<"*e f*">` matches the file `e f`). So quotes apparently only "escape" spaces. So odd.

Comment: @Schwern Updated, with a correct explanation -- `glob` uses `[]` for _character class_, easily confirmed and documented.

Comment: I have found a workaround, and that's to wrap any `[` or `]` in `[]`.  So:
`perl -e '$d="test [[]dir[]]"; print -e glob qq("$d"/.ignore*); print "\n";'` matches `"test [dir]/.ignoreme"`

Comment: @Scott Alright, that puts `[` and `]` themselves each in a character class, thus effectively escaping their special meaning.  (But you have to type it while `quotemeta` escapes all special chars without having to know what's in a variable.  It's very curious though :) I added to the answer another way to handle this -- escape with `quotemeta` to start, when you write to a variable.